# What exactly is the purpose of/use case for VXLAN?

Tags: networking, vxlan, data-center

I understand what it does in that it creates an overlay layer 2 network over an underlay but when would you use it? What is the problem it’s solving?

Comment: Think about the case of moving VMs between datacenters / regions. You need the same network to be everywhere, but simple bridging falls apart quickly with distance.